# Struggling to use one variable for multiple parameterization markers in pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Using pandas I am doing a parametrized sql query shown in the snippet of code below. I have one variable a date that I am feeding in as a marker for both the inception and expiration in the where clause, but I don't want to have to add this in twice as a parameter as it is the same variable. I'm sure there is a way around this but I can't find it.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dt = datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)

select_sql = """Select Inception, Expiry From TableTest Where Inception <= ? and Expiry >= ?"""

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(select_sql, conn, params=[dt,dt])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python's [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) syntax to create the query string that you want to pass to the SQL function. The date values need to be surrounded by quote marks in the SQL query.

```py
select_sql = f"SELECT Inception, Expiry FROM TableTest WHERE Inception <= '{dt}' AND Expiry >= '{dt}'"

print(select_sql)
```

```
SELECT Inception, Expiry FROM TableTest WHERE Inception <= '2021-10-01' AND Expiry >= '2021-10-01'
```

Then you can pass this query string to the pandas function with `pd.read_sql_query(select_sql, conn)`, as you don't need the `params` argument anymore with this approach.

Comment: Thank you. How would you pass that into pd.read_sql_query? And is this safe from an injection attack perspective? I have a longer script where the same parameter is fed in even more times, so that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Just `pd.read_sql_query(select_sql, conn)`, as you don't need the `params` argument anymore with this approach. I'm not a security expert, but it's hard to imagine a possible attacking scenario if you make sure that all the inserted values are in a valid date format.

Comment: Thank you, I had some trouble before with the date format, error was saying there was a conflict between date and int and parametrisation resolved this issue.

Comment: ```f"""Select Inception, Expiry From TableTest Where Inception <= '{dt}' and Expiry >= '{dt}'"""``` This works. If I take the single quotation marks away from the {dt} I get this error: [SQL Server]Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int (206).

Comment: Do you want to make the above adjustment to the answer and I'll mark it as correct? Thanks.